# MongoDB find only the newest combination of fields

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have 3 collections:

1:

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "5f37dad305c1b9403bfe808b"
},
"nextBilling": {
    "isAutomatic": true,
    "isRedeemedForFutureBilling": false,
    "time": 1000,
    "duration": 1000
},
"userToken": "aaaa",
"__v": 0
}
```

2:

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "5f37dad305c1b9403bfe323b"
},
"nextBilling": {
    "isAutomatic": true,
    "isRedeemedForFutureBilling": false,
    "time": 2000,
    "duration": 1000
},
"userToken": "aaaa",
"__v": 0
}
```

3:

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "5f37dfj1b9403bfe323b"
},
"nextBilling": {
    "isAutomatic": true,
    "isRedeemedForFutureBilling": false,
    "time": 1000,
    "duration": 1000
},
"userToken": "bbbb",
"__v": 0
}
```

These are payments from users, and I want to get every users' payments, but only and only their last payment (which can be determined by `nextBilling.time`). So what I want to get at the very last is collections number 2 and 3. Users are identified by the `userToken`, so what I actually want is all combinations of (`userToken` and `nextBilling.time`) where `nextBilling.time` is the largest and only one result should be returned for each `userToken`.

What i'd do in mySql for achieving this would be sth like:

```
SELECT *  FROM payments WHERE (user_token, next_billing_time) IN (SELECT user_token, MAX(ts_in_sec) FROM payments group by user_token)
```

I'm a bit lost about what I should do in mongoDB for this. I'm using mongoose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [aggregate()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/index.html),

- [$sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/index.html) by `nextBilling.time` descending order

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $sort: { "nextBilling.time": -1 } },
```

- [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) by `userToken` and set first `nextBilling` and `id`

```
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$userToken",
      id: { $first: "$_id" },
      nextBilling: { $first: "$nextBilling" }
    }
  },
```

- [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/index.html) to show required fields

```
  {
    $project: {
      _id: "$id",
      userToken: "$_id",
      nextBilling: 1
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/b1nqd86TVbd)

Answer (score 1):

You can do :

```
const result = await ModelName.aggregate([
    {$group: {_id: '$userToken', "time": {$max: "$nextBilling.time"}}}
])
```